# How do I add items to a List<int> type of property of an instance?

Tags: c#

So, I want to have two List<> types for an instance of the class, and then add integers to these lists with a method, but it doesn't want to work this way and have no idea how to correct it. The `AttachWagonFromLeft()` method doesn't add anything to the list, I try to referenc the instance with `this`. Does anyone have any idea? Thanks.

```
`
public class TrainComposition {
    private List<int> LeftWagons;
    private List<int> RightWagons;

    public List<int> LeftWagons1 { get => LeftWagons; set => LeftWagons = value; }
    public List<int> RightWagons1 { get => RightWagons; set => RightWagons = value; }

    public void AttachWagonFromLeft(int wagonId) {
        this.LeftWagons1.Add(wagonId);
    }

    public void AttachWagonFromRight(int wagonId) {
        this.RightWagons1.Add(wagonId);
    }
[...]
`public static void Main(string[] args) {

        TrainComposition tree = new TrainComposition();
        tree.LeftWagons1 = new List<int>();
        tree.RightWagons1 = new List<int>();
        tree.AttachWagonFromLeft(7);
        tree.AttachWagonFromLeft(13);
        Console.WriteLine(tree.DetachWagonFromRight()); // 7 
        Console.WriteLine(tree.DetachWagonFromLeft()); // 13
`
```

Comment: You can use auto properties, which might help reduce confusion

Comment: What part isn't working? Your code works fine for me. LeftWagons has 2 items at the end.

Comment: It really helps to follow the style rules and use camel casing (lowe caps) for fields and pascal casing (Upper case) for properties.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your class, you could use [Auto-Implemented Properties (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties):

```
public class TrainComposition
{
    public List<int> LeftWagons1 { get; set; }
    public List<int> RightWagons1 { get; set; }

    public void AttachWagonFromLeft(int wagonId)
    {
        this.LeftWagons1.Add(wagonId);
    }

    public void AttachWagonFromRight(int wagonId)
    {
        this.RightWagons1.Add(wagonId);
    }
}
```

You did not provide the DetachWagonFromRight and DetachWagonFromLeft implementation, but assuming it print the last parameter from the list:

```
public int DetachWagonFromLeft()
{
    return this.LeftWagons1.Last();
}
```

Your code is not working as expected because you are adding twice to the left and none to the right:

```
tree.AttachWagonFromLeft(7);
tree.AttachWagonFromLeft(13);
```